# Question about segment of code in C programming course

Tags: c

I'm doing a course online in C and this is the assignment:

> You are still conducting linguistic research! This time, you'd like to
>   write a program to find out how many letters occur multiple times in a
>   given word. Your program should read a word from the input and then
>   sort the letters of the word alphabetically (by their ASCII codes).
>   Next, your program should iterate through the letters of the word and
>   compare each letter with the one following it. If these equal each
>   other, you increase a counter by 1, making sure to then skip ahead far
>   enough so that letters that occur more than twice are not counted
>   again. You may assume that the word you read from the input has no
>   more than 50 letters, and that the word is all lowercase.

The solution they provide:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char word[51];
    int length = 0;
    int i, j;
    char swap;
    int repeats = 0;

    scanf("%s", word);

    while (word[length]!='\0')
    length++;

    //Sort the word by alphabetical order    
    for(j=0;j<length-1; j++) {
        for(i=0;i<length-1;i++) { 
            if (word[i] > word[i+1]) {
                swap = word[i];
                word[i]   = word[i+1];
                word[i+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    i = 0;

    //Check for repeating characters in the sorted word
    while (i<length-1) {
        if (word[i]==word[i+1]) {
            repeats++;
            j=i+2;

            //Continues through the word until it reaches a new character
            while (j<length && word[i]==word[j]) 
                j++;
            i = j;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", repeats);

    return 0;
}
```

I understand everything up to code "//check for repeating characters in the sorted word//".
Specifically I don't understand the purpose or logic of "j=i+2" (especially the "+2") and how it relates to the next section of code "//continues through the word until it reaches a new character". I don't think this was adequately explained in the tutorials provided by the course.

Any insight or feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: `especially the "+2"` At that point characters `i` and `i+1` were determined to be equal. The loop that follows starts at the next character which is `i+2` and goes forward checking for more consecutive characters equal to the `i` and `i+1` one.

Comment: The key to most problems (and especially character problems like this one) is to take out a 8.5x11 sheet of paper and write the word out in big letters. Then step though the code manually marking what character is currently being operated on during each iteration. This same method works for virtually all logic problems. You can sketch and erase much faster than trying to manipulate boxes in a text editor...

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your word is printed on paper, and you examine it through a small hole in a cardboard sheet. You can only see 2 letters at a time.

First, look at the beginning of the word. Identical letters? If not, shift by 1 position and repeat. If yes:

You found one repeated letter. Now you should find where the repeated run ends. To do that, shift your examination hole to the end of the repeated run.

It is possible to do this shift correctly in several ways. The way they implemented is until the first of the two visible letters is different from the repeated letters you found earlier. To do that, first you should shift by 2 positions, because at that position in code you know that the two letters are identical. But you could shift by 1 position instead — that would be correct too.

Another correct implementation — shift until you see two different letters in the hole. This may be easier to implement and more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you mind also explaining why "i=j" a few lines down in the code? I realize I also don't understand the logic of that as well.